# I want to show email id's in dropdown list. I want Person name shown as selected value related to that email after selecting email

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ngselect

I want email id's in my dropdown list. Whenever I select a email it will show the user name in input field.

```
<ng-select [items]="UserData" [addTag]="addTagFn" [hideSelected]="true" multiple="true"
    bindLabel="name" class="ng-custom" appendTo="body" placeholder="User name [(ngModel)]="selectedValues">
    <ng-template ng-option-tmp let-item="item" let-item$="item$" let-index="index">
      {{item.email}}
     </ng-template>
</ng-select>



.ts File

    selectedValues;
    UserData: any[] = [];
     UserDataNames = [
    { name: 'xyz', email: 'xyz@email.com' },
    { name: 'abc', email: 'abc@email.com' },
  ];

    ngOnInit() {
        this.UserDataNames.forEach((c, i) => {
            this.UserData.push({ id: i, name: c });
        });
    }

    addTagFn(name) {
        return { name: name, tag: true };
    }
```

[image]

For eg. :- UserData = [{name:'xyz',email:'xyz@email.com'},{name:'abc',email:'abc@email.com'}].
When I am select xyz@email.com from the list It will show xyz as selected value. Also I found some custom templete solution but it is also not working.It is showing like this

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example? I don't see that you are using `UserData` value.

Comment: hi @YongShun can you check it now. Also It can allow us to add custom tags as well.

Comment: Besides fixing for the syntax issue, I can't reproduce your issue: [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-vxxkqs?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Comment: I added my ts file code now you can check

Comment: I am adding custom text also and I need a new list with existing tags and custom tags as well

Comment: Hi YongShun, I hope you understand now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was when you were iterating the `UserDataNames` array and adding the element in the `UserData` array.

```
this.UserData.push({ id: i, name: c });
```

You are assigning the object to the `name` field. And there is no `email` field.

Instead, you should add the element to the `UserName` array as:

```
this.UserDataNames.forEach((c, i) => {
  this.UserData.push({ id: i, name: c.name, email: c.email });
});
```

Or you can work with the `map` function:

```
this.UserData = this.UserDataNames.map((c, i) => ({
  id: i,
  name: c.name,
  email: c.email,
}));
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-vxxkqs?file=src%2Fmain.ts)